# Is there a way to create a Chapter in JWPlayer from the JS?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, jwplayer

I am looking for the JWPlayer (v7) equivalent to something like videojs' markers ([videojs-markers](https://github.com/spchuang/videojs-markers)).

In JWPlayer, I am able to use Chapters (using a VTT file) to signify these markers, and that is great. But I want to be able to allow the user to create a marker (i.e. chapter/bookmark) with a button, real time. The button will both POST the marker with the server, but will also instantly show it as a Chapter in the video (ideally without having to reload the VTT file).

I will like to do something like

```
myPlayer.addChapter({
   'start':'00:00:01.234', 
   'end':'00:00:02.234',
   'title':'This is a marker at 1.234sec'
})
```

It this is not possible, is there at least a way to ask the player instance to reload the VTT file from the server, where I can have the file include the new marker. Of course, that will be inefficient, but may be acceptable.

Thanks

Comment: It has to be done using VTT. If you need to load a new VTT from the server, you would need to do another jwplayer().setup() with the new VTT file loaded...

Comment: But if I have to re-setup, wouldn't that cause the video to also have to be re-fetched? That would be bad.

Comment: Yes, it would. The VTT can't be reset by itself though.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please consider this a feature request. Being able to both create Chapters real time, or asking the instance to reload the VTT would be a great.